# How to extend Java class in Nashhorn JavaScript and add class member variables

Tags: java, nashorn, extending

I try to create an instance of a class that extends a Java class, and in that instance add some class member variables. Here's my attempt:

```
var ui = Java.extend(javax.swing.JPanel, { 
    cb : new JCheckBox("A checkbox", true),
});
```

However, the Nashorn interpreter throws this error:
"TypeError: function **noSuchMethod**() { [native code] } is not a constructor function"

What am I doing wrong? Nashorn didn't complain when I added an instance of a custom class, like se.datadosen.util.Stopwatch, but it throws this error when I try to add that JCheckBox.

(I know components are added to panels with the .add() call, but this question is really about how to add class member variables to a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

`Java.extend` allows you to add **methods** implemented in JavaScript to a Java class (actually, to create a new class that subclasses the Java class). It does not allow you to add arbitrary properties, at least according to the documentation. See [The Nashorn Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html), which says:

> You can extend a class using the Java.extend() function that takes a Java type as the first argument and **method implementations (in the form of JavaScript functions)** as the other arguments." (emphasis added)

You are attempting to add an **object** as a property of the class, at least the way your code is presently written.

Comment: Thanks. Qualifying JCheckBox with javax.swing. actually makes that declaration "compile", but it doesn't seem to work anyway. Is there no way to add properties to a Java subclass? This can be done in BeanShell, which is scripted Java.

Answer (score 0):

javax.swing.JCheckBox instead of JCheckBox ?

Comment: Thanks. Weird error message for missing javax.swing